# Meaning of "only the means of communication is different"

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is an excerpt from *Advanced Business English*:

> Conventions for mail, letter, and fax are the same. Only the means of communication is different.

As I understand it, this means that only the used ‘equipment’ is different, while the ‘writing forms’ are similar: recipients, subject line, date. ect.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: More context needed.

Comment: sorry, if you are not engaged in "formal" English.  that is the 2. time you are , so stop downvotes .  the context is there.

Comment: @FrankMK I didn’t downvote, but I did just edit to make the question clearer, because it was quite difficult to figure out what you were actually asking. When asking questions, take a moment to read it through a few times, use blockquotes, paragraphs and such things to make it as readable as possible, and in particular consider whether the question is clearly worded and presents information in a logical, progressive manner. That way, people will be much more likely to understand you immediately and not downvote your question or vote to close it as unclear.

Comment: Yes Janus, thats fine. And i love this exchange. But sometimes I simply dont have the time to make it well for everyone.  If it is not clear, that I was asking for the meaning of "MEANS" so go on...... We all have to take critic, isn´t it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's "sentence" not "sentense" (just in case that WASN'T a typo).

Second, yes it is correct to say "only the means of communication is different".

"Means" in this context means "method" or "way of doing something" and despite being spelled with an "-s" it is a **singular** noun (not a plural), so "is" would be the correct verb to use.

**e.g.**

Only the means of communication **are** different <--- INCORRECT!

Only the means of communication **is** different <--- CORRECT!

*Source/Further reading [Search for "Means (noun)"]:*
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/mean

Comment: yes, a typo :-) but noticed. !! Thanky you.

Comment: It’s not true that _means_ is only a singular noun and “the means… are” is incorrect. It’s a plural noun in origin, and while it can certainly be used as a singular noun, it is also its own plural and can be used with a plural verb. It’s not like _news_, which is singular only.

Comment: I think that I found a tricky one :-)

Comment: Yes, "means" CAN be a plural noun... but in this context it's singular. I should've clarified that, but thanks for pointing it out.